# Asp.net core5.0 API in Docker. How to acces AWS parameter store?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core

I have a Asp.NetCore5.0 application.

I build a docker image like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/ App/
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The application should use AWS Parameter Store like:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var envName = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.ToString().ToLower();
                    config.AddSystemsManager($"/{envName}", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

**It is working on my local machine** (I installed the AWS Cli on my local machine) without any problems.

**But it is not working inside a Docker Container** on my Linux server 
(**AWS Cli installed on the server [not inside the docker]** and tested as well). 
The server is not a part of the AWS Cloud.

Exception

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured
   at Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.Validate()
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor(AWSCredentials credentials, ClientConfig config)
   at Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient..ctor(AWSCredentials credentials, AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementConfig clientConfig)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I already tried to pass the *No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured* as ENV and so on but without a success.

```
docker run -d -p 12080:80 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=thisIsMyId -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret --name nameoftheapi dockerhubuser/nameoftheapi:262

docker run -d -p 12080:80-v $HOME/.aws/credentials:/home/app/.aws/credentials:ro --name nameoftheapi dockerhubuser/nameoftheapi:262
```

Same exception.

How can I access AWS Cli from the inside of a Docker Container ?
Do I need the AWS Cli inside Docker at all? Is there any other solution to do something like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "is not working" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: sorry about that, please see the updated post.

Comment: You don't need AWS Cli inside Docker. Show us how do you pass ENV into container

Comment: I tried to pass the creds with docker run  -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=thisIsMyId -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to pass the folder with the aws credentials to the docker container.

```
docker run -d  -p 12080:80 -v /root/.aws:/root/.aws:ro  --name nameofthecontainer dockerhubuser/someimage:264
```

I installed the aws cli on the docker-host-server as well. I think, I can uninstall it now. I just need the credentials.

I created an user with the access to the parameter store on AWS. 
Created some parameters and a access policy as well.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:12345678:parameter/abc/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

the last problem I had was the wrong parameter path

```
/abc/Release/def/ghi/jkl
instead of
/abc/Production/def/ghi/jkl
```

based on wrong assumption about the environment in this code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    var envName = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.ToString().ToLower();
                    config.AddSystemsManager($"/{envName}", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

I'm so happy now.